# Is there a way of providing polymorphic type discrimination similar to Rust's enums?

Tags: javascript, typescript, polymorphism

I've recently returned to JS/TS after coding a lot in Rust and this is a feature I really miss.

So suppose that I have a value which may be an instance of `Cat` or an instance of `Dog` and depending on which class it is from, I want to perform different logic. Since Javascript cannot do `classname ==` (I think?), what I usually rely on is also passing a string indicating the class like this:

```
function groomAnimal(animal: Cat | Dog, animalType: 'cat' | 'dog') {
    if (animalType === 'cat') {
        (animal as Cat).trimNails();
    } else {
        (animal as Dog).trimFur();
    }
}
```

I hate this because it's unwieldy and the compiler cannot guarantee that the caller correctly fulfills the contract. On the other hand, in Rust this would be quite elegant:

```rust
enum Animal {
    Cat(CatData),
    Dog(DogData),
}

fn groomAnimal(animal: Animal) {
    match animal {
        Cat(catData) => catData.trimNails(),
        Dog(dogData) => dogData.trimFur(),
    }
}
```

Basically, the `enum` itself which indicates the "class", also holds the "class" data and thus obtaining the data and checking the data type are the same operation

Is there any pattern in typescript that allows for polymorphic function signatures while ensuring at compile time that the code operates on the correct data types?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could  create a composable structure with `Cat/Dog` and some identifier attribute, bit similar to your approach but differently.

Something like this,

```
type Animal = Cat & { animalType: 'Cat' } | Dog & { animalType: 'Dog' }
```

You `groomAnimal` method would now take the composed structure,

```
function groomAnimal(animal: Animal) {
    if (animal.animalType === 'Cat') {
        animal.trimNails();
    } else {
       animal.trimFur();
    }
}
```

Here is one small sample where I create a cat and pass it to the `groomAnimal` method,

```
const tom = {
    trimNails() {
        console.log('Trimming nails')
    }
}

groomAnimal({ ...tom, kind: 'Cat'})
```

In you case, you said you parse these from some api calls. You could already prepare your `Animal/Animals[]` object when parsing and use that later when grooming.

And, of course, the compiler can guarantee that the caller actually correctly fulfils the contract as you can see from the code.

Comment: I know this is quite old at this point, but in retrospect this is definitely the right solution. I don't think I appreciated it at the time, but it's very clean and straightforward

Answer (score 2):

Keeping a separate value indicating the type is very error prone. If `Cat` and `Dog` are class types (not just interfaces), you can use [`instanceof`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#instanceof-type-guards) to verify its type directly:

```
class Cat {
    trimNails() {}
}

class Dog {
    trimFur() {}
}

function groomAnimal(animal: Cat | Dog) {
    if (animal instanceof Cat) {
        // animal must be Cat, so you can call trimNails()
        animal.trimNails();
    } else {
        // animal must otherwise be a Dog, so you can call trimFur()
        animal.trimFur();
    }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately they are interfaces. They are parsed from JSON loaded from the server. I dont think there is an easy way to make them classes without incurring some overhead

Comment: But actually, this gives me an idea. I could basically just wrap the interfaces in classes and use `instanceof` which is actually pretty similar to the rust solution. I think this is better than what I was doing